# Custom Header with token in PASOE Business Class Entity with Web Service?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have a PASOE Business Class Entity setup as a Web Service. I'm trying to determine how to create a custom header that will allow me to pass in a hashed token. Is this something that I need to upgrade to 11.7.4 for DOH(OpenEdge.Web.DataObject.DataObjectHandler)? Or is this something that I simply add into a method that's defined in the class? Apologies, for the lack of code to illustrate my situation, but I'm not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a Business Entity with the web transport then you're using the DOH, and the below applies. If you're using the rest transport then you are **not** using the DOH, and are more limited in your choices.

There is doc available on the DOH at https://documentation.progress.com/output/oe117sp/index.html#page/gssp4/openedge-data-object-handler.html - it's for 11.7.4 but largely applies to all versions (that is, from 11.6.3+). This describes the JSON mapping file,  which you'll need to create an override to the default, generated one.

If you want to use the header's value for all operations, then you may want to use one of the DOH's events. There's an example of event handlers at https://github.com/PeterJudge-PSC/http_samples/blob/master/web_handler/data_object_handler/DOHEventHandler.cls ; you will need to start that handler in a session startup procedure using `new DOHEventHandler()`  (the way that code is written is that it makes itself a singleton).

You can now add handling code for the `Invoking` event which fires before the business logic is run.

If you want to pass the header value into the business logic you will need to

- Copy the generated mapping file `<service>.gen` to a `<service.map>` , in the same folder. "gen" files are generated and will be overwritten by the tooling
- In the .map file, add a new `arg` entry. This must be in the same order as the parameters to the BE's method.
- The JSON should look something like the below. this will read the value of the header and pass it as an input parameter into the method.

```
    { "ablName": "<parameter_name>",
      "ablType": "CHARACTER",
      "ioMode": "INPUT",
      "msgElem": {"type": "HEADER", "name": "<http-header-name>"}
    }
```